Uncaught TypeError: isObject is not a function
i am working on a project using Laravel / vuejs vite and i have a problem in IconBase.js in ant-design-vue package and exactly on :
 var twoToneColorPalette = reactive({ primaryColor: '#333', secondaryColor: '#E6E6E6', calculated: false });
when this code call reactive function "Default vuejs function" , it's return this exception:
reactivity.esm-bundler.js:927 Uncaught TypeError: isObject is not a function
    at createReactiveObject (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:927:8)
    at reactive (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:891:10)
    at IconBase.js:13:27

Keep in mind that when i run npm run build the app working fine but when i run npm run dev it's generate this error . Any help please !!
Evreything without result

The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Considering that isObject https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/efd090b50f4e507bd95fdbd15f1e5439511b4213/packages/reactivity/src/reactive.ts#L249 comes from vue/shared, it can be deduced that there's a problem with project setup that prevents the import from working correctly. Considering that this happens in third-party package, make\ sure there are no multiple @vue folders in node_modules, this would mean there are duped vue packages, which may result in unexpected problems

Is the problem solved? If so, can you share the solution?

Not yet , i am still facing the problem
